# MS graph api get teams using javascript returns no results

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

i am using graph api javascript example from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript

and my code is like:

```
async function(req, res) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      // Redirect unauthenticated requests to home page
      res.redirect('/')
    } else {
      let params = {
        active: { calendar: true }
      };

      // Get the access token
      var accessToken;
      try {
        accessToken = await tokens.getAccessToken(req);
        console.log("access token is:", accessToken)
      } catch (err) {
        req.flash('error_msg', {
          message: 'Could not get access token. Try signing out and signing in again.',
          debug: JSON.stringify(err)
        });
      }

      if (accessToken && accessToken.length > 0) {
        try {

          console.log("vik testing stuff12 for teams")

          const user = await graph.getTeams(accessToken)
          console.log("graph me:::", user)
        } catch (err) {
          req.flash('error_msg', {
            message: 'Could not fetch events',
            debug: JSON.stringify(err)
          });
        }
      } else {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Could not get an access token');
      }

      res.render('calendar', params);
    }
  }
```

getTeams is

```
  getTeams: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const events = await client
      .api('/me/joinedTeams')
      .version('beta')
      .get();

    return events;
  }
```

this prints no results and no error. if I replace 'me/joinedTeams' to just 'me' then it returns logged in user details.

Comment: I was able to get joined team details just by adding team.readbasic.all to OAUTH_SCOPES in .env file. Make sure that your are using your work account or [demo account](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program).  Please let us know if you are still stuck on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can got a response successfully, so it seems no error with your code as you said if you call **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me** you can get user information.

And I tried to call this API using my account(my account hasn't joined any Teams), and got response like below, so if you got the same response as mine, `perhaps you need to check if you have joined any Teams`:
[image]

On the other hand, following the document, this API needs several permissions. So please obtain your access token when debug and use JWT tool to decrypt it to check if the access token `have enough scope`.
[image]

And I used the same request and got Teams information after adding my account to a team.
[image]

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-12-04T19:52:15",
      "request-id": "4a10513a-f755-4b8c-be7b-edd1d3382dae",
      "client-request-id": "4a10513a-f755-4b8c-be7b-edd1d3382dae"
    }
  }
}

is what I get in postman

Comment: @Vik Hi, I am not sure why you got this response, so I tried many cases. My account is a   work account and I used Azure ad ROPC flow to get the access token, In this scenario, I can always get 200 response whether I have MS teams license or have joined a Team. And If I haven't added correct API permission, I won't get 404 too. The only I can get 404 is that I used client credential flow to get access token and when I used this token I got this error. So I chose to use this url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/joinedTeams`. Wish it would help.

Comment: strange.. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id} this works but https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/joinedTeams still fails with same 404. so basically using me or actual id my results are consistent.

Comment: emmm, would you mind offering your detail operation on getting an access token. I mean which flow you used and how did you enter your parameter. Or providing the decryption result of your access token?  As you can see, no problems with account, url and code. Any other fields?

Comment: i used https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start?appID=174854b3-6a97-4154-8760-2e56c29092a7&appName=My%20Node.js%20App&redirectUrl=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback&platform=option-node to generate the app in nodejs . this gives me access token

Comment: decrypted token https://www.dropbox.com/s/mey7c4aj7fv3xal/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-08%20at%208.25.03%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry. I run your sample code, and I am really not familiar with nodejs, I assume it uses implicit grant flow because readme.md asks to check ID token when registering the ad application, but this won't lead to 404 error. So I have no other ideas.